# Problem with combining Manipulate and ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting, manipulate, parametric-functions

I've beein trying to solve this problem but somehow I just can't combine Manipulate and ParametricPlot3D.

```
trobrid[g_, t_, a_, b_] := Module[{X, Y, Z, tang, norm, binorm, k, l},
g == {X[t], Y[t], Z[t]};
tang = D[g, t]/Simplify[Sqrt[D[g, t].D[g, t]]];
norm = D[tang, t]/Simplify[Sqrt[D[tang, t].D[tang, t]]];
binorm = FullSimplify[Cross[tang, norm], t > 0];
Manipulate[
   ParametricPlot3D[g, {t, a, b}],
   Graphics3D[{
       Red, Arrow[{g, tang + g} /. {t -> s}],
       Blue, Arrow[{g, norm + g} /. {t -> s}],
       Purple, Arrow[{g, binorm + g} /. {t -> s}]
 }], {s, a, b}]
]
```

This is the error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Clear[g, t, a, b, s, trobrid]
trobrid[g_, t_, a_, b_] := DynamicModule[
  {X, Y, Z, tang, norm, binorm, k, l},
  {X[t], Y[t], Z[t]} = g;
  tang = D[g, t]/Simplify[Sqrt[D[g, t].D[g, t]]];
  norm = D[tang, t]/Simplify[Sqrt[D[tang, t].D[tang, t]]];
  binorm = FullSimplify[Cross[tang, norm], t > 0];

  Manipulate[
   Show[
    ParametricPlot3D[g, {t, a, b}],
    Graphics3D[
     {Red, Arrow[{g, tang + g} /. {t -> s}], Blue, 
      Arrow[{g, norm + g} /. {t -> s}], Purple, 
      Arrow[{g, binorm + g} /. {t -> s}]}]
    ],
   {s, a, b}
  ]
 ]
```

Then:

```
trobrid[{Cos[t], Sin[t], t/3}, t, 0, 3 Pi]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Issues in your original code:**

1. You should use `DynamicModule` with `Manipulate`, rather than `Module`.
2. `g == {X[t], Y[t], Z[t]};` is incorrect as an assignment; you really want to assign {X[t], Y[t], Z[t]} to the existing value of g, so you want `{X[t], Y[t], Z[t]} = g`, and you want to use `Set` (`=`), not `Equal` (`==`).
3. You need to wrap your graphics objects in `Show` within `Manipulate` to combine them and show them superimposed.

Comment: Thank you very much. And what is the command if I want to show for example Torsion and Curvature at each point of the curve. How do I get that into the graphic?

Comment: @zermelovac not sure, I haven't really parsed your code for function, just for syntactic correctness. The Frenet-Serret equations may be relevant to you; see [previous questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Frenet+Serret+is%3Aq) on this site, and the [docs for FrenetSerretSystem](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrenetSerretSystem.html) perhaps?

Comment: Let me correct myself. How do I insert text inside a graphic, somewhere in the frame.

Comment: @zermelovac Oh! I misunderstood; that's fortunately an easier task :-) Try adding this inside your `Graphics3D` list of objects within the `Manipulate`: `Inset[Style["s = " <> ToString@Round[s, 0.1], 28, Black], Scaled[{0.3, 0.2, 0}]]`. See how it works, then you can use it as a template of sorts to roll your own.